# Hiding ribbon in SharePoint 2013 based on permission level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, permissions, ribbon

I am trying to hide ribbon in SharePoint 2013 based on different permissions level.For example admin who is the owner of the site would be able to see ribbon and other users would not be able to see ribbon.

For this I used following tag around the ribbon in master file using SharePoint 2013 designer.But now only the admin is able to see the ribbon and for all other users following error is popping up

**Tag I am using**

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">    
    <div id="s4-ribbonrow"  >
    </div>
    </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

**Error I am getting**

[image]

Comment: what is your permission in the site?

Comment: I have one site owner with full control and the rest are in the visitors(view only) group

Comment: Did you try the option in answer section

Comment: You are having unmatching spelling of the `<SharePoint` part of the control declaration also. It has ha capital `P` in the opening tag but not in the closing tag

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display a content to the user only with 'Full Control' permission level use the below snippet

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="FullMask">
<div id="s4-ribbonrow"  >
</div>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

**Different base permissions**

```
EmptyMask : Has no permissions on the Web site. Not available through the user interface.
ViewListItems : View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.
AddListItems : Add items to lists, add documents to document libraries, and add Web discussion comments.
EditListItems : Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, edit Web discussion comments in documents, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.
DeleteListItems : Delete items from a list, documents from a document library, and Web discussion comments in documents.
ApproveItems : Approve a minor version of a list item or document.
OpenItems : View the source of documents with server-side file handlers.
ViewVersions : View past versions of a list item or document.
DeleteVersions : Delete past versions of a list item or document.
CancelCheckout : Discard or check in a document which is checked out to another user.
ManagePersonalViews : Create, change, and delete personal views of lists.
ManageLists : Create and delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, and add or remove public views of a list.
ViewFormPages : View forms, views, and application pages, and enumerate lists.
Open : Allow users to open a Web site, list, or folder to access items inside that container.
ViewPages : View pages in a Web site.
AddAndCustomizePages : Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a SharePoint Foundation–compatible editor.
ApplyThemeAndBorder : Apply a theme or borders to the entire Web site.
ApplyStyleSheets : Apply a style sheet (.css file) to the Web site.
ViewUsageData : View reports on Web site usage.
CreateSSCSite : Create a Web site using Self-Service Site Creation.
ManageSubwebs : Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.
CreateGroups : Create a group of users that can be used anywhere within the site collection.
ManagePermissions : Create and change permission levels on the Web site and assign permissions to users and groups.
BrowseDirectories : Enumerate files and folders in a Web site using Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 and WebDAV interfaces.
BrowseUserInfo : View information about users of the Web site.
AddDelPrivateWebParts : Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page.
UpdatePersonalWebParts : Update Web Parts to display personalized information.
ManageWeb : Grant the ability to perform all administration tasks for the Web site as well as manage content. Activate, deactivate, or edit properties of Web site scoped Features through the object model or through the user interface (UI). When granted on the root Web site of a site collection, activate, deactivate, or edit properties of site collection scoped Features through the object model. To browse to the Site Collection Features page and activate or deactivate site collection scoped Features through the UI, you must be a site collection administrator.
UseClientIntegration : Use features that launch client applications; otherwise, users must work on documents locally and upload changes.
UseRemoteAPIs : Use SOAP, WebDAV, or Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 interfaces to access the Web site.
ManageAlerts : Manage alerts for all users of the Web site.
CreateAlerts : Create e-mail alerts.
EditMyUserInfo : Allows a user to change his or her user information, such as adding a picture.
EnumeratePermissions : Enumerate permissions on the Web site, list, folder, document, or list item.
FullMask : Has all permissions on the Web site. Not available through the user interface.
```

Comment: Problem is NOT content but only ribbon.I want to control only ribbon visibility.

Comment: the ribbon div is placed in Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl right? then what is the issue.

Comment: Same error message is popping out "Sorry the site has not been shared with you".But when I remove the tag then all the users have access to site.

Comment: Try with different base permissions. Start from the lesser permission like ViewPages and check still you get the error

Comment: thanx..........but how would I check the permissions on  my site.As far as I know admin has got full control and is able to access but all the other users are in the visitors(view) group and these are the ones having problem when I place those tags.

Comment: Were you able to access the site permissions page through site settings?

Comment: yes I do have access.